# How do I prevent this from happening from my AFK Command (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an `AFK` command but the problem is when do `!afk` in my server and I type something else on a different server, it says *"Welcome back ur not afk anymore"* even though I did `!afk` in my server. I am not sure how to fix this

The Code:

```
bot.afk = new Map();
bot.on("message", message => {
 
    if (db.has(message.author.id + '.afk')) {
        message.channel.send("welcome back!")
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk')
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.message')
    }
})
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    message.mentions.users.forEach(user => {
        if (db.has(user.id + '.afk')) message.channel.send(`That user is AFK!`)
    })
})
 
 
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'afk':
            db.set(message.author.id + '.afk', 'true')
            db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', message.content.split(' ').slice(1))
            message.channel.send(`U are now afk`)
            break;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the channel id in your db for the user so:

```
let isafk = db.fetch(`isafk_${message.channel.id}_${message.author.id}`) //however you fetch your db values
if(isafk) {
//code for if is afk in that channel
} else {
return;
}
```

Comment: can i do message.guild.id instead of channel id?

Comment: @WideIrenaKan1 yes, that should work fine

Comment: yes you should go for guild id instead of channel id.